# How To Highlight Selected Dates In Date Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

First is there a way to not highlight the current day.  Second is there a way to highlight specific days like the way the current day was highlighted?

Here is the code i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/calendar-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var dates = [new Date(2011, 9 - 1, 19),
             new Date(2011, 9 - 1, 20),
             new Date(2011, 9 - 1, 20),
             new Date(2011, 9 - 1, 21),
             new Date(2011, 10 - 1, 31)];

$(function() {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    });


    $('#datepicker').click(function() {
        // put your selected date into the data object
        var data = $('#datepicker').val();

        $.get('getdata.php?date=' + data, function(data) {
            $('#events').html(data).show('slow');
        });
    });

    function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                return [true, 'highlight'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }
});
</script>

<style>
#highlight, .highlight {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>  

</head>
<body>


<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;margin: 0 10px 0 0;font-size: 72.5%;"></div>

<div id="events" style="float:left;font-size: 10pt;">
<p>Select a date on the calendar to see events.</p>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First is there a way to not highlight the current day.

Yes, you can take away the highlighting by removing `.ui-state-highlight` and `.ui-state-hover` classes from the anchor element.

> Second is there a way to highlight specific days like the way the current day was highlighted?

Yes, either add the classes for highlighting the current day to those days you want to have highlighted, or override the CSS with `.ui-state-highlight`'s style.

For the first approach, here's an example code snippet:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
}).click(function() {
    // question 1
    $('.ui-datepicker-today a', $(this).next()).removeClass('ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover');

    // question 2
    $('.highlight a', $(this).next()).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
});
```

See the first approach in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Aut9b.
See the second approach in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Aut9b/1/.

Comment: I realize this is a few years old, but is there a way to do this if a text box has an AJAX calendar Extender on it? I have been searching for days and posted a few questions here as well trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use beforeShowDay option of jQuery UI date-picker to highlight selected dates in date-picker. Here the simple code:

```
$( function() {
    // An array of dates
    var eventDates = {};
    eventDates[ new Date( '08/07/2016' )] = new Date( '08/07/2016' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '08/12/2016' )] = new Date( '08/12/2016' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '08/18/2016' )] = new Date( '08/18/2016' );

    // datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            var highlight = eventDates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above JavaScript will add `event` class on selected dates. Now you will need to define the style for selected dates. For the complete guide, you can check the source link mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

try this to hightlight the dates in datepicker

$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( 'setDates', ['02-22-2024','02-23-2024','02-24-2024'] );