# Datepicker link on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Jquery Datepicker To Link To It ?

http://jsfiddle.net/EbA7B/

İt's not working.

Me Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-tr.js"></script>


    <script>
$(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "tr" ] );
        $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
                $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Not getting your problem.

Comment: Me with my code have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have tried your code check here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EbA7B/6/). But I am not able to get your problem. Elaborate please.

Comment: oh no no.   
One code connection my code,but ıt's not working.I want to make the link like replant.  
my English is bad

Comment: Follow this on stackoverflow: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504819/how-to-highlight-selected-dates-in-date-picker